# Is it a good practice to fetch client user's data from database on every api call?

Tags: python, flask, jwt

For authentication in my REST API, I am using JWTs, which only contain the client user's UUID.

To check if the user is not blocked or has rights to execute a specific endpoint, I fetch the user's data from a PostgreSQL database using the UUID of the JWT, and verify if the user is allowed to execute.

Is it a good practice to do a database operation for securing every API call?

Also thought about storing roles and rights in the JWTs but what if these roles and rights change in the database and the JWTs data becomes stale? Is there any solution to the stale data?

Comment: It’s not really a best practice to use JWTs for such things, the consequence is that you still have to get back to the D’n to validate things, why would you need a ‘signed session ID’ in that case? See also http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Answer (score 1):

You have to check *some* data store for staleness with JWT.

If you conclude with performance tests and measurements that accessing a PostgreSQL DB for every request would be too slow, then you optimize that part. Maybe optimize your DB performance by changing the data structure or configuration. Or use a completely different database just for this purpose. Bad practice would be trying to optimize this prematurely.

Here's an article that talks about [how to manually expire JWTs](https://medium.com/devgorilla/how-to-log-out-when-using-jwt-a8c7823e8a6), it describes an example with using Redis:

> An implementation would probably be, to store a so-called “blacklist” of all the tokens that are valid no more and have not expired yet. You can use a DB that has TTL option on documents which would be set to the amount of time left until the token is expired. Redis is a good option for this, that will allow fast in memory access to the list. Then, in a middleware of some kind that runs on every authorized request, you should check if provided token is in The Blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

TL DR: No its not :-)

In general JWT's are not the most suitable solution for scenario you describe, you are already facing the first trouble of it now.

Because you better store stateless information in your JWT, otherwise you would be better of using other authentication solutions.

> Conclusion
>
> Stateless JWT tokens cannot be invalidated or updated, and will introduce either size issues or security issues depending on where you store them. Stateful JWT tokens are functionally the same as session cookies, but without the battle-tested and well-reviewed implementations or client support.
>
> Unless you work on a Reddit-scale application, there's no reason to be using JWT tokens as a session mechanism. Just use sessions.

source: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

And some other related posts:

http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/19/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions-part-2-why-your-solution-doesnt-work/

https://medium.com/@yuliaoletskaya/can-jwt-be-used-for-sessions-4164d124fe23

https://logrocket.com/blog/jwt-authentication-best-practices/

Most security consultants / auditors I spoke to also are very strong in there statements about JWT, they are widely overused and have a specific problem domain.

But if you really want/need to, I would follow @ekuusela's answer, especially given:

> Bad practice would be trying to optimize this prematurely.